# Why would a file generated by mysqldump be substantially larger than the data directory

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-5.5

- I have a MariaDB server - 5.5.60
- I have a database `xyz` that has both MyISAM and InnoDB tables
- The majority of the tables are MyISAM but in this database in particular, the data is mainly in InnoDB tables.

If I run `du -sh /var/lib/mysql/xyz` I get `11M`

If I run `mysqldump -u root -pXXX "xyz" > xyz.sql` the resulting file is `371M`

I can use the `xyz.sql` file to restore the database just fine.  With other databases I have had all MyISAM tables and never noticed much of a difference in size.

Why is the `.sql` file so much larger than the actual database directory?  Is there something I should do differently when using mysqldump with a database with InnoDB tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is normal.

with a version 5.5.60 default settings for innodb **innodb_file_per_table** = 0
it means - data stored not in files inside the database folder, but in global innodb file.

You can check it in /var/lib/mysql
file - ibdata1

after version 5.6 default value for **innodb_file_per_table** settings is 1

ibdata1 is still extremely important, but data stored in separate files similar for myisam.